# can't post the data from form on a pop-up?

Tags: javascript, php, popup, http-post, popupwindow

i would like to made a pop-up window for my login and signup sites. but there's a problem with this code, can't post the data from the form and the submit button didn't work when clicked. someone help me please. thanks.

here it is the index.html with the pop-up:

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login_form"></a>
            <div class="popup">

                <h2>Welcome Guest!</h2>
            <form id="formlogin" name="formlogin" method="POST" action="login_proses.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  autocomplete="on"> 
                <p>Please enter your login and password here</p>                
                <p>
                    <label for="username">Login</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" required />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="popupUploadForm()"> 
                </p>                        
            </form> 
            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
            </div>
    <script>
    function popupUploadForm(){
    var newWindow = window.location.href='login_proses.php';
}
</script>
```

and here it is login_proses.php that pick the data form, but it's always failed, and always go into index.html as else condition.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";

if (isset($_POST["username"])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from member where username='$username'");

    if ($sql && mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        if($password == $result['password']){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Selamat Datang $username'); 
                                         window.location.href='member.php';</script>";  
         }
        else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password salah, silahkan coba lagi');history.go(-1)</script>"           ;
        }
    }

    else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Username tidak ada dalam database');history.go(-1)</script>"    ;       
    }
} else {
    header("location:index.html");
} ?>
```

Comment: You need to post the data, not open only a new window o_o

Comment: but i would like to post the data into a new window o_o

Comment: use jquery or ajax ;) or get parameter adding the data to the new window url

Comment: maybe jquery would be the solution, but i'm still a newbie. :D must learn more about jquery and how to get it. thanks @MarcoMura

Comment: you can use window.location.href='login_proses.php'; but you need to add to the url the get parameter and change your php file to work with get params